# Process Exit error : Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to execute a stored procedure from SQL developer but I get an error:

> Process exited - disconnecting database

How to solve this error?

I tried to run the query from SQL Plus but SQL Plus is not installing into my machine. Please help. How to run the stored procedure from SQL developer?

> Error
>   Connecting to the database XYZ.
>   Process exited.
>   Disconnecting from the database XYZ.

I tried to run this stored procedure from sql developer by right click ---> run and put values like '2019-05-12' = StartDate  and '2019-05-13' = StopDate . StartDate  and StopDate are datetime . Please help . I'm searching through net but can't find proper solution for this .

Comment: I don't think that's an error message. What are you expecting to happen when you run your stored procedure? Show us your code, explain how you're running it, and show us what comes back.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I updated my question with code but I don't think there is any issue in store procedure but the process is exited with this error Connecting to the database xxxx.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database xxxx.

Comment: sorry, no one here can help you w/o seeing your code...you, on your own, can try taking the anonymous block that the 'execute' dialog generates, pasting that into a sql worksheet, and executing with F5 and see what comes back.